# Android: Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android

I have searched the internet high and low for the answer to this error:

Non-static method 'getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' cannot be referenced from a static context

I have not found anything so I have come here. Here is the code I use for adding the info as extras:

```
Intent OpenList = new Intent(this, ListRandom.class);
OpenList.putExtra("ListItem1",List.get(1));
OpenList.putExtra("ListItem2", List.get(2));
OpenList.putExtra("ListItem3", List.get(3));
OpenList.putExtra("ListItem4",List.get(4));
OpenList.putExtra("ListItem5", List.get(5));
```

And here is getting the Extras, where I get the error:

```
    Intent OpenList = getIntent();
    ListItem1 = Intent.getStringExtra("ListItem1");
    ListItem2 = Intent.getStringExtra("ListItem2");
    ListItem3 = Intent.getStringExtra("ListItem3");
    ListItem4 = Intent.getStringExtra("ListItem4");
    ListItem5 = Intent.getStringExtra("ListItem5");
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am growing as a programmer!

Comment: duplicate of [What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922145/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694566/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972764/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
 Intent OpenList = getIntent();
ListItem1 = Intent.getStringExtra("ListItem1");
ListItem2 = Intent.getStringExtra("ListItem2");
ListItem3 = Intent.getStringExtra("ListItem3");
ListItem4 = Intent.getStringExtra("ListItem4");
ListItem5 = Intent.getStringExtra("ListItem5");
```

to

```
 Intent OpenList = getIntent();
ListItem1 = OpenList.getStringExtra("ListItem1");
ListItem2 = OpenList.getStringExtra("ListItem2");
ListItem3 = OpenList.getStringExtra("ListItem3");
ListItem4 = OpenList.getStringExtra("ListItem4");
ListItem5 = OpenList.getStringExtra("ListItem5");
```

Use the `Intent` object that you created here

```
Intent OpenList = getIntent();
```

Just like any other class, using `Intent.getStringExtra("words");` is calling it in a `static` way and if you look at the [Intent Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)  `getStringExtra(String name)` is not a `static` method so you create an instance if `Intent` with `Intent OpenLIst = getIntent();`

Also, to stick with Java programming standards you should use mixed-case for your variable names so `OpenList` would be `openList` and `ListItem1` would be `listItem1`. This isn't necessary for compiling obviously but its a good idea to try and stick to standards

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
    ListItem1 = Intent.getStringExtra("ListItem1");
```

You are using a method (i.e. `getStringExtra(String name)`) on a class (i.e. `Intent`), which is a `static` approach.

Instead, you should use a method on an object (i.e. `OpenList`) for a non-static approach.

Thus, your code should be changed to:

```
    ListItem1 = OpenList.getStringExtra("ListItem1");
```

And be applied to ListItem2, ListItem3, and so on.

`OpenList`