# Android Cannot update ArrayAdapter because "Non-Static method 'notifyDataSetChanged()' cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, static, android-arrayadapter

I'm using a bit of code to help me with pulling data from the web called WebRequest (https://github.com/delight-im/Android-WebRequest).  It provides a callback for retrieving asynchronous data.  However I can't update my ArrayAdapter because I get an error "Non-Static method 'notifyDataSetChanged()' cannot be referenced from a static context"

Now, I've seen a number of similar questions here.  Some suggest putting the notifyDataSetChanged command in the Adapter class itself. Some suggest using a Handler and some suggest using a Loader.  However I have had no luck actually implementing these solutions.  Here's my code:

```
    new WebRequest().get().to(stringSQLUrl).executeAsync(new WebRequest.Callback() {
        public void onSuccess(int responseCode, String responseText) {
            try {
                DataHistory = CsvUtil.fromCsvTable(responseText);
                DataHistory.remove(0);  //Removes header row
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Main pullWebData","Error converting from CsvTable: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            DataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  //  <-- ERROR HERE
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        DataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   // <-- ALSO ERROR HERE
                    }
                });
        }
        public void onError() {
            Log.e("Main pullWebData","Error pulling data from web");
        }
    });
```

I also defined this Handler in my activity thinking I could call it and it would update the ArrayAdapter, but I got the same error here:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        WeightAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Lastly I created a method inside the Adapter definition to notify itself, but calling that gave me the same static/non-staic error:

```
public void updateMe() {
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Long story short - there are a ton of questions seemingly about this same topic and lots of advice, but I have been unsuccessful in implementation.  Can anyone show me exactly how I'd implement this?

Thank you!

One other thing: I was considering switching from Web data to an Azure SQL DB, but that would also use a callback and I presume have the same issue?

Comment: have you read [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972764/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context?rq=1) and do you understand what a static reference is?

Comment: I had not read that one specifically. I think I understand what static means here.  Or at least I think notifyDataSetChanged is non-static because it belongs to a specific implementation of the ArrayAdapter (DataAdapter in my example).  I do not understand why the context here is considered Static or where I have a non-static context to call this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only call static methods using `ClassName.methodName();` However, `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not a static method. i.e. `notifyDataSetChanged()` works depending on the instance of your adapter.

To make sure that this works, you should use `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the object of the custom adapter.

If you have something like :

```
DataAdapter customAdapter = new DataAdapter(//params);
listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

You should call :

```
customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: smh. I was mixing up the class with the instance.  You're right - I was calling notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter class and not the instance I had created.  Thank you!